# ensamblador, como agregar datos a una matriz?

Tags: array, ensamblador, arquitectura, nasm, x86

Estoy empezando en ensamblador,Como puedo agregar datos a una matriz en memoria? Recibo como entrada M(filas) y N(columnas), Estoy intentando agregar datos a una matriz(MxN) en memoria, al parecer estoy agregando en otras direcciones.
Este es el codigo que utilizo para leer y cargar los datos a memoria.

```
xor esi,esi ; ESI = 0 (ESI se utiliza como indice)
mov ebx,1       ;contadorFila
leer_filas:
    mov ecx,1       ;contador Columna
    leer_columnas:
        ;Input datos
        PutLInt ebx             ;fila
        PutLInt ecx             ;columna
        PutStr pedirDatos
        GetLInt eax
        ;Asignar input a memoria
        mov [arreglo+ESI*4], eax
        inc esi
        inc ecx
        cmp ecx,[columna]       ;ecx <= columnaInput 
        jna leer_columnas      ;menor 
    inc ebx
    cmp ebx,[fila]              ;ebx <= filaInput 
    jna leer_filas                    ;menor
```

Y al momento de mostrar, me salen ceros, y no los datos que agrege,de esta manera es como muestro la matriz (de forma lineal)

```
mov ecx,esi
xor esi,esi
mostrar_siguiente:          ; Mostrar datos lineal en memoria
    PutLInt [arreglo+ESI*4]
    PutStr imprimirEsp
    inc esi
    loop mostrar_siguiente      ;ecx se va decrementando
```

Comment: Solo tenia que declarar la variable matriz con una tamaño mas grande, como "arreglo resd 1000"

Comment: Hola @Spider-Man, si has dado tú mismo con la solución, porque no te contestas a ti mismo en una respuesta y la validas, así tendrás más reputación dentro de ésta comunidad, he visto haces varias veces, contestarse a sí mismo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al revisar el código, tenia la variable `arreglo resd 8` por lo que solo me permitía agregar los primeros datos ingresados, solucione aumentando el espacio en memoria que dejaría para agregar los siguientes datos, por `arreglo resd 1000`

Comment: Si está fue la solución definitiva, puedes proceder a marcarla como respuesta.